# PowerShell to change .Net config file

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, scripting

I am trying to script some changes to .NET `machine.config` file and I keep running into issues. I have used all the examples on the web and no matter which ones I use I get different errors. The below snippet is what I have gotten the closest with. However, instead of it adding to the config file in the "Path" it is just creating a new document with all the code in it?

```bsh
$path = "c:\Temp\Machine.config"
[xml]$machineConfig = Get-Content $path

$Channelsxml = $machineConfig.CreateElement("Channels")
$Channelsxml.SetAttribute ref= "http server" port="443"
$node.AppendChild($Channelsxml) | Out-Null

$machineConfig.Save("c:\Temp\Machine.config")
```

It creates a document in mydocuments with all the code in it instead of changing the config file located in the path given. I also get the below errors:

```
+ $Channelsxml.setAttribute ref= "http server" port="443"
+                           ~~~~
Unexpected token 'ref=' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

What I need it to do is add the following:

```xml
<channels> 
<channel ref="http server" port="443"/> 
</channels>
```

Comment: What I need it to do is add the following to the config file:

<channels> 

<channel ref="http server" port="443"/> 

</channels>

Comment: You do not have $node populated anywhere. Also, .setAttribute expect its parameter (Name,Value) between parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the `SetAttribute()` method is wrong. You want the attributes added to a child node of the node you created (so you need to create that child as well), and you need to add 2 individual attributes to that child node.

```
# create node <channel ref="http server" port="443"/>
$n1 = $machineConfig.CreateElement('channel')
$n1.SetAttribute('ref', 'http server')
$n1.SetAttribute('port', '443')

# create node <channels> and append node <channel .../>
$n2 = $machineConfig.CreateElement("channels")
$n2.AppendChild($n1) | Out-Null
```

Then you need to append `$n2` to a node in `$machineConfig`:

```
$parent = $machineConfig.SelectSingleNode('...')
$parent.AppendChild($n2)
```

Replace `...` with an appropriate [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to select the node you want to append to.